# VBA Input Box and destination cell

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a workbook where when a job is completed the user selects complete from a dropdown box in column G, when the cell changes to complete, a message box prompts the user to enter Y or N in the same row but in column M. I would like to use an Input Box instead of a Message box for Y or N but have no idea how to input the answer into the correct cell in column M. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Below is what I currently have. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "COMPLETE" Then
            MsgBox "If Warranty job  please enter Y in correct cell in column M"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use something like `Target.Worksheet.Range("M" & Target.Row).Value = <myValue>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to use an Input Box instead of a Message box

Friendly advice: don't. You'll then have to control for user input, which could be anything. In this example using `InputBox` we have to `Trim` the input, take only the left-most character of the result, and enforce a consistent case, otherwise we have to consider whether "y" = "Y" = "YES" = "yes" = "YeS", etc... and possibly to handle invalid input (what if the user inputs "G", or "123456789", etc.), which adds more complexity where it's really not needed.

```
Dim userInput as String
GetUserInput:
userInput = InputBox("Is this a warranty job? Y/N")
userInput = UCase(Left(Trim(userInput),1)
If userInput = "Y" Then

    ' put the value "Y" in column G
ElseIf userInput = "N" Then
    ' do nothing
Else
    ' If user input is not Y or N, send them back to the input box
    GoTo GetUserInput
End If
```

Of course you *can* do this if you want, but for a simply Yes/No option, the `MsgBox` is actually designed to accommodate this quite easily, with standard button options.

Instead, use a `MsgBox` with the options Yes/No and control the input to worksheet directly, rather than prompting the user to do it manually. In the example below I put the "Y" in the same row as `Target` cell, column M. Modify as needed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim mbResponse as VbMsgBoxResult

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target = "COMPLETE" Then
        mbResponse = MsgBox("Is this a warranty job?", vbYesNo)
        If mbResponse = vbYes Then
            Target.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Y"

        Else:
            'do nothing

        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You. I get what you mean about the input box and the complexity around user input. The Msgbox suggestion is perfect, Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

How wbout:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "COMPLETE" Then
            roww = Target.Row
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Cells(roww, "M").Value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Warranty job?  Please enter Y or N", Type:=2)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I took the advice of David Zemens and went with the YesNo Message box, it does away with any user input errors. Thanks though.